# python logging - how to handle the log filename when created by parent class

Tags: python, logging, global

In a python project I use several classes which need to log their operations. I solved this by creating an auxiliary class like

```
import logging
class LoggerModule():
    def __init__():
        self.logger = ... (creation of a logger given a config file)
```

where the 'filename' field of the file handler is specified in a configuration file.
All the project classes inherit from it like this

```
class MyClass(LoggerModule):
    def __init__():
        super.__init__()

    def foo():
        self.logger.info('HELLO!')
```

What I would like to do is that, if I launch the main module N times on the same machine, all the N Python processes will write into the same log filename. Instead, I would like each process to write into a distinct log filename, let's say info_{N}.log. It could be done storing the filename into globals() python variable, then make the LoggerModule class get the filename from it, but before than usign globals() I'd like to know if there are different and cleaner alternatives.